# Detecting dev mode: Set secure cookie for production, insecure for dev mode

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT's Cookie.setCookie to set login cookies for my site. I want to make them secure cookies (my site always runs over https) but development mode can only run over http.

What's the best way to set up a switch so that the insecure code runs in devmode and the secure code runs in production?

Comment: Actually, since GWT 2.3, DevMode can run with SSL if you want: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.3/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/shell/jetty/README-SSL.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GWT.isProdMode()`:

```
  /**
   * Returns <code>true</code> when running in production mode. Returns
   * <code>false</code> when running either in development mode, or when running
   * in a plain JVM.
   */
```

Comment: What constitutes a "plain JVM"? In our production environment, the GWT application is deployed to Tomcat...I would assume Tomcat does not use a "plain JVM"?

Comment: I think it just means "any JVM."  Production mode runs in a JavaScript machine, not a Java machine.